# `Insert Note` - fill picture. As in the existing macro to tie “msoFileDialogFilePicker”?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this:

```
Sub Special_Note2_FillPicture(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim myComm As Comment
      If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        If MsgBox("The cell already contains a note, delete?", 4) - 7 Then
          ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
      End If

    Set myComm = ActiveCell.AddComment
        With myComm.Shape
          .Height = 110
          .Width = 200
          .AutoShapeType = 1             'form
'          .Fill.UserTextured
          .Fill.UserPicture "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\TEST.jpg"
          .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          .DrawingObject.Font.Name = "Consolas"
          .DrawingObject.Font.FontStyle = "normal"
          .DrawingObject.Font.Size = 8
        End With
          'emulate the choice of "Change note"
           SendKeys "+{F2}"
End Sub
```

I want to place Instead:

```
.Fill.UsLerPicture "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\TEST.jpg"
```

Add to open the window for choosing pictures from my PC. I find this and i don't know how to use?

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

I have added the code that is required. It can be Shorten as well, but to be accurate this should be the way.

```
Sub Special_Note2_FillPicture(control As IRibbonControl)

    Dim img As FileDialog
    Dim i_add As String

    Set img = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        img.AllowMultiSelect = False
        img.Title = "Select the Image!"
        img.Show

    If img.SelectedItems.Count < 1 Then        
        MsgBox "No Image Selected"        
    Exit Sub

    Else            
        i_add = img.SelectedItems(1)
    End If


    Dim myComm As Comment
      If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        If MsgBox("The cell already contains a note, delete?", 4) - 7 Then
          ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
      End If

    Set myComm = ActiveCell.AddComment
        With myComm.Shape
          .Height = 110
          .Width = 200
          .AutoShapeType = 1             'form
'          .Fill.UserTextured
          .Fill.UserPicture i_add
          .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          .DrawingObject.Font.Name = "Consolas"
          .DrawingObject.Font.FontStyle = "normal"
          .DrawingObject.Font.Size = 8
        End With
          'emulate the choice of "Change note"
           SendKeys "+{F2}"
End Sub
```

Comment: yes it works but doesn't see a picture ️ in the folder. For example i have .jpg and .png

Comment: This `(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` should have been `(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`, Corrected Now

Comment: ··· now it works good but I still have some issue, after inserting "Picture" I see this window  https://imgur.com/QsBoOQh

Comment: Which line shows the Error ? And this is not the issue you described in your question. Ideally you should ask a new question :)

Comment: ··· 0Key maybe I can show yuo [Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/oFqTBA4fFpJM). _Buy the way_  i have «Microsoft Office 365 2019».

Comment: Not sure about that Error @rediffusion , Maybe you can ask a new question for it. Don't forget to mark this as answer. All the Best :)

Comment: ··· today i solve this **error** with [SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57349113/11552254). If you upvote ☑️ my question I would appreciate it! Regards!

Comment: Sure thing @rediffusion